How to check the structured log in human mode
I know we are using structured log for better log analysis.
But who can tell me is that much easier for human to read below logs?
{"@timestamp":"2024-03-24T23:03:13.693+08:00","@version":"1","message":"Release executor io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup@1e499f1","logger_name":"io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider","thread_name":"SpringApplicationShutdownHook","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000}

All I want to see is
【2024-03-24T23:03:13.693+08:00】 【SpringApplicationShutdownHook】io.lettuce.core.resource.DefaultEventLoopGroupProvider【DEBUG】: Release executor io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup@1e499f1

Just like old style when people check the log file or console, is that quick way to do that?
Thanks

I suppose you can have another additional logger and define the required format for it

thanks Alex, yes, maybe we can define two kinds of format, one is for machine, one is for  human.

Yes, we can define several log files with different formats. The details depends on chosen logging system, but for the standard Spring Boot configuration we can define in application.yml
logging:
  level:
    root: debug
  file:
    name: human.log
  pattern:
    file: "[%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz}] [%t] %class [%p]: %msg%n"

With this pattern we got in the file human.log what you want to have
[2024-05-21T09:45:32.576EST] [main] example.feature.Hello [DEBUG]: example message

For more details please see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

thanks a lot @Alex, we need human.log
